# On creation of campaign in Pardot, Send an emails to users and Tack if the users have accessed/Open that mail

Tags: email-alert, campaign, pardot

We need to build a Campaign in Salesforce Marketing Application called Pardot, Where we need to create a Campaign which will send out an email with a webinar link to the list of users and we need to track if the users have accessed the links? and we need to send three emails with 3 different link and track the activity by user.

Comment: Would you please explain more elaborately? In which part of these processes you face with a problem, what did you do and what did you get as a result?

Comment: Hi Selim, Thank you for looking this Issue. I am new in Pardot and I have a requirement that on creation of campaign to send an emails to the list of users and Track the status of that emails. Do let me know If you have any references to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Redirects](https://www.pardot.com/blog/custom-redirects/) to track whether the link has been accessed. Depending on your use case (do you e.g. want to send reminders to recipients who haven't visited the link), you could use [completion action](https://www.pardot.com/blog/completion-actions/) on the links to remove the recipient from a list - leaving you with a list of non-clickers. This can be used as a target list for a follow up email.

Brgds
Lukas

Comment: You’re welcome. Remember to mark the answer as accepted